# Cant use Merge inside foreach for existed nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am expecting he following query to create nodes (only if exits) and relations by a given source node (1) and a list(2) this way:

```
MERGE (p1:C9{userId: '1'}) WITH p1, [{userId:"2"}] AS users 
FOREACH (user IN users | MERGE 
((p1)-[r1:follow]->(:C9 {userId: user.userId})))
```

Thats the outcome:

[image]

Now if I am executing this query again by switching the node id's this way:

```
 MERGE (p1:C9{userId: '2'}) WITH p1, [{userId:"1"}] AS users 
    FOREACH (user IN users | MERGE 
    ((p1)-[r1:follow]->(:C9 {userId: user.userId})))
```

We got this:

[image]

neo4j **duplicated** for me the node with id=1. I want it to merge in case of existed nodes.

I expected to see only two nodes connected to each other by merging existed nodes.

any idea what I should fix?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally avoid `FOREACH` when I can use an `UNWIND`, so I would start with something like this:

```
MERGE (p1:C9 {userId: '1'})
WITH p1, [{userId:"2"}] AS users 
UNWIND users AS user
MERGE (p1)-[r1:follow]->(:C9 {userId: user.userId})
```

Sometimes you also want to separate your node creation from your relationship creation.  If you do both at the same time, I think that Neo4j can think that you want a unique combination of node (with properties) and relationship.

```
MERGE (p1:C9 {userId: '1'})
WITH p1, [{userId:"2"}] AS users 
UNWIND users AS user
MERGE (p2:C9 {userId: user.userId})
MERGE (p1)-[r1:follow]->(p2)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. why unwind would be better in that case?

Comment: `UNWIND` is easier for me to reason about.  It also makes it cleaner because I can have separate lines rather than everything being inside the `FOREACH`.  Lastly, clauses inside of a `FOREACH` just feel wrong to me...  Maybe it just feels un-query-language-ish.  I know that's all pretty vague ;)

Comment: One thing that I also just thought of: If you need multiple `MERGEs` or `ON (MATCH|CREATE) SET` or whatever, that's just more stuff that you're throwing into your `FOREACH`, but to me makes it even more messy

Comment: What about scaling? since neo4j is only rest ill need to do many concurrent merges like this. any suggestions from your experience ?

Comment: Not sure I understand.   Do you mean the HTTP REST API?  If so, the API does support running commands in batch, if that's helpful.  Check out the transactional endpoint documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` within `FOREACH`.

But you have to understand the semantics of `MERGE`. It tries to `MATCH` a full pattern and if it *does not find it* it will fully `CREATE` that pattern.

You in your case you try to find a *pattern within the context* of p1 and not globally and if not found it will create it within the context of p1.

So if you change your query to:

```
MERGE (p1:C9{userId: '2'}) 
WITH p1, [{userId:"1"}] AS users 
FOREACH (user IN users | 
  MERGE (p2:C9 {userId: user.userId})
  MERGE (p1)-[r1:follow]->(p2)
)
```

I.e. create p2 first and then `MERGE` the relationship, it will work.

Comment: Now I understand. thank you. what about FOREACH vs using UNWIND as @Brian shows in his answer? Performance aspects? any other aspects?